# Publishing Google presentation doc in web using google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a automatic process that gets Google presentation docs urls (from a google app script using the method file.getUrl()) and publish them in a website through a iframe.

The problem is that the Google presentation doc is displayed in an edit mode inside my website page ... I would like to display it in a presentation mode.

I know there is a option inside the document menu file -> publish on the web where you can get a presentation mode url and then use it in the iframe ... but

I need to get that url (in a presentation mode) from my google app script process in order the process to continue being 100 % automatic ...

Anyone know how ca i do that ?

Thanks very much in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the url from:

[https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/{id}/edit?usp=sharing](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/%7Bid%7D/edit?usp=sharing)

To:

[https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/{id}/present?usp=sharing](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/%7Bid%7D/present?usp=sharing)

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)